# In C#, is it possible to have a separate Router and Controllers?

Tags: c#, api, controller, refactoring, url-routing

I'm currently refactoring an ASP.NetCore 2.18.0 project with a Controller which has far too many responsibilities.  I actually want to divide it into 4 separate Controllers. The problem is, I don't want to burden the consumers with updating their solutions, so while I want the logic to live on the different controllers, I want to keep the routes as they currently are:

ContractListController

- /api/v1.0/Contract
- /api/v1.0/Contract/listAll/{customerReference}
- /api/v1.0/Contract/listOne/{customerReference}/{contractNumber}

ContractFactoryController

- /api/v1.0/Contract/Vollmacht
- /api/v1.0/Contract/Gripop
- /api/v1.0/Contract/Sepa

ContractLinkController

- /api/v1.0/Contract/renew/{customerReference}/{contractNumber}
- /api/v1.0/Contract/renewlnk/{contractNumber}

ContractDocuSignController

- /api/v1.0/Contract/dsReturn
- /api/v1.0/Contract/dsReturn/{contractNumber}/{sp}/{c1}/{c2}/{c3}

Is there a way I can create a router which will direct Http requests to the appropriate Controller instead of using annotations on the Controller?

FWIW, I can't find `MapControllerRoute` anywhere in the project. The Controller has [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")] and then methods have attributes like [Route("listAll/{customerReference}")]

Comment: Products like Azure _API Manager_ can do that, redirecting certain incoming requests to your new controllers.  Apart from your new controller code, no specific re-routing code is required to be written by you.  APIM does that for you.

Comment: asp.net? asp.net core? What do your current `.MapControllerRoute(`'s or `[Route("...")]` look like? What have you tried?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, ASP.NetCore 2.18.0.   I can't find `.MapControllerRoute(` anywhere in the project.  The Controller has `[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]` and then methods have attributes like `[Route("listAll/{customerReference}")]`.  I haven't tried anything yet as I before @MickyD's reply above, I had no idea what I might try.

Comment: Don't comment with those details, clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually simpler than I expected.

My original controller class had attributes like this:

```
[RequireHttps]
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class ContractController : Controller
{
  // whatever
}
```

All I needed to do was:

1. Create the four controllers, each with the same Attributes and extending `Controller`
2. Replace `[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]` with `[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Contract")]`
3. Delete the original controller.